# Creating an object when named pipe receives message

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, named-pipes

I have been creating a single instance application using a Mutex.

In the `Sub Main` code, the app checks to see if it is the first instance, if so it starts the form (called `MainForm`). The `MainForm` creates an asynchronous named pipe server to receive arguments passed from a new instance.

If the app is not the first instance, Sub Main creates a named pipe client, sends the command line arguments through to the first app, and proceeds to exit.

The application is tab-based, and each command line argument is a file path, which is used to create the tab. The argument is received (I can `MsgBox()` it), but when I try to pass it as an argument to the control I'm creating, nothing happen

`Pipe` classes:

```
Namespace Pipes

' Delegate for passing received message back to caller
Public Delegate Sub DelegateMessage(Reply As String)

Public Class PipeServer
    Public Event PipeMessage As DelegateMessage
    Private _pipeName As String

    Public Sub Listen(PipeName As String)
        Try
            ' Set to class level var so we can re-use in the async callback method
            _pipeName = PipeName
            ' Create the new async pipe 
            Dim pipeServer As New NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.[In], 1, PipeTransmissionMode.[Byte], PipeOptions.Asynchronous)

            ' Wait for a connection
            pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer)
        Catch oEX As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub WaitForConnectionCallBack(iar As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            ' Get the pipe
            Dim pipeServer As NamedPipeServerStream = DirectCast(iar.AsyncState, NamedPipeServerStream)
            ' End waiting for the connection
            pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar)

            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(254) {}

            ' Read the incoming message
            pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, 255)

            ' Convert byte buffer to string
            Dim stringData As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Debug.WriteLine(stringData + Environment.NewLine)

            ' Pass message back to calling form
            RaiseEvent PipeMessage(stringData)

            ' Kill original sever and create new wait server
            pipeServer.Close()
            pipeServer = Nothing
            pipeServer = New NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.[In], 1, PipeTransmissionMode.[Byte], PipeOptions.Asynchronous)

            ' Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
            pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer)
        Catch
            Return
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Class PipeClient
    Public Sub Send(SendStr As String, PipeName As String, Optional TimeOut As Integer = 1000)
        Try
            Dim pipeStream As New NamedPipeClientStream(".", PipeName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous)

            ' The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
            ' If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
            pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut)
            Debug.WriteLine("[Client] Pipe connection established")

            Dim _buffer As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SendStr)
            pipeStream.BeginWrite(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, AddressOf AsyncSend, pipeStream)
        Catch oEX As TimeoutException
            Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AsyncSend(iar As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            ' Get the pipe
            Dim pipeStream As NamedPipeClientStream = DirectCast(iar.AsyncState, NamedPipeClientStream)

            ' End the write
            pipeStream.EndWrite(iar)
            pipeStream.Flush()
            pipeStream.Close()
            pipeStream.Dispose()
        Catch oEX As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

`MainForm` logic:

```
#Region "Pipes"
Public ArgumentPipe As New Pipes.PipeServer
Public Sub RecievedMessage(reply As String)
    GetMainformHook.Invoke(MySTDelegate, reply)
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeServer()
    AddHandler ArgumentPipe.PipeMessage, AddressOf RecievedMessage
    ArgumentPipe.Listen(_pipename)
End Sub

Public Delegate Sub RecievedMessageDel(txt As String)
Public MySTDelegate As RecievedMessageDel = AddressOf SetText
Public Sub SetText(txt)
    MsgBox(txt)
    TabStrip1.AddTab(txt.ToString)  'PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetMainformHook() As MainForm
    Return Application.OpenForms("MainForm")
End Function

Public Shared Function GetTabControl() As TabStrip
    Return CType(Application.OpenForms("MainForm"), MainForm).TabStrip1
End Function

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     InitializeServer()
End Sub

#End Region
```

In `Sub Main` when sending argument:

```
Dim _pipeClient = New Pipes.PipeClient()

If cmdArgs.Length > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To cmdArgs.Length - 1
        _pipeClient.Send(cmdArgs(i), _pipename, 1000)
    Next
End If
```

`_pipename` is a global string like `"myappv6"`

Am I missing something?

I'm thinking this has something to do with cross threading, but can't pinpoint where to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Most of the command line forwarding is much more easily implemented using the VB Application Framework.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28838693/1070452) for an example

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix and this is available with the Enable application framework unchecked, right?

Comment: @Plutonix The same problem occurs :/. I can display the Strings but cannot create an object with them. EDIT: I had to invoke it on the Form, now it works. Thank you