# How to pass arguments to an application that is already running?

Tags: vb.net, arguments, runtime, mutex

I have an application written in VB.NET and I have a file association that will trigger a specific function if opened from that file type.

The only thing is that If the application is already open and a user clicks on an associated file, it opens another instance of the application.

Basically, I would like to have the *currently* running instance of the application handle any incoming arguments from a double click on an associated file. Here is some pseudo-code to help understand.

```
if(application.isAlreadyRunning){
application.doSomething(filePath);
}
else{
proceed normally...
}
```

I've looked into mutexes, and they allow me to ensure that only one instance of the app is running, but then I need to pass the filename to the *currently* running instance.

Thanks!

P.S. I forgot to mention that I am using ClickOnce to deploy the app and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData` to retrieve the "arguments"

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Pass arguments to first instance of a Single Instance App](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28831765/1070452).