# Setting a VB.Net tray app to single-instance if Application Framework is disabled?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create a VB.Net tray app that launches directly to the tray, instead of being sent there by a hidden startup form. I found a CodeProject article that explains how to do this, and it works perfectly. It describes how to disable the Application Framework (and then re-enable it later), so the startup object can be set to a module with the startup code.

But after the Application Framework is re-enabled, how do I programmatically enable "Make single instance application"..?

Since the framework is initially disabled, all of its checkboxes are also disabled, including the one for single instance. I checked in both of the following namespaces, and could not find any property named "SingleInstance", or anything similar or seemingly related:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application
System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
```

So how can it be done?

For reference, here is the article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET

Comment: You need the ApplicationFramework for the single instance restriction, but that doesnt mean you cant start from a Sub Main. The code in  [Pass arguments to first instance of a Single Instance App](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28831765/1070452) should help with that part (Method 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find a "SingleInstance" property or anything similar because it does not exist.  The concept of single instance is compiler magic that the visual basic compiler adds for you when you check the "Make single instance application..." box in your project properties.  If you want to use the visual basic magic with a tray only application, you'll need to manage several parts of the startup code yourself.

You'll need two pieces of code to make this work.

1. Inherit from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase` and override the `OnRun` method.  You'll create the tray app here using the methods of WindowsFormsApplicationBase to help.
2. A `Sub Main` entry point for the application which creates an instance of your application base and calls the `OnRun` method.

You can read [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx) for more information on how the `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` works.

Comment: Hi - I ended up at here after reading referenced information and https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-net-a-practical-guide/#eleventh

Comment: Hi - I've been reading information referenced above and [Creating Tray Applications in .NET: A Practical Guide](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-net-a-practical-guide/#eleventh). I've been trying to get this to work in a pure tray situation (ie without MainForm, because I don't want one shown at startup) with no success. Apparently it can be done but my efforts thus far have been fruitless. Please would you be so kind as to share some code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3085342 You should ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for response but I'm a little confused as I've seen many questions pasted with the dreaded "duplicate" flag which makes you appear too lazy and dumb to read through existing information and then try and apply it to your situation. So I was enquiring if you would be able to elaborate on your answer. If you still feel it warrants a new question I will take that approach. Thanks.